# Does quantum mechanics explain the behavior of subatomic particles to the exclusion of classical mechanics, or are they both applicable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, electrons, atoms

On the one hand, the cathode ray experiment conducted by JJ Thomson seems to indicate that the radius of path deflection of an electron beam is also governed by the same centripetal force equation that describes large, macroscopic objects ($\frac{mv^2}{r}$). In addition the electron beam has a defined curvilinear motion and not the probability distribution that describes electron clouds surrounding the atomic nucleus.

On the other hand, we are taught at the same time that the idea that electrons circularly orbit the nucleus in the classical sense is erroneous because electrons follow quantum mechanical models for behavior due to their size.

Having said that, do quantum mechanics and classical mechanics both describe electrons, and if so is QM just an "add-on"? (As in, both baseballs and electrons follow classical mechanics, but electrons also follow QM)

When they actually do conflict does QM always take precedence?

Is there some sort of pattern to identify when QM takes precedence over classical descriptions when dealing with subatomic scale? Or is it just case-by-case memorization?

Does the concept of wave-particle duality help determine at all *when exactly* you should apply one theory over the other in conceptualizing particle behavior?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classical mechanics is generally thought of as a *limit* of quantum mechanics. That is, everything follows the rules of quantum mechanics, but for some things the errors you make if you treat them with classical mechanics is negligible for the specific use case.

If you get non-negligible conflicts, you have to throw away the *classical* description, not the quantum description. This is not about "memorization", it's about judging whether or not the quantum effects are relevant to the situation you want to describe.

Comment: OK, so if I'm understanding you correctly, it's about how much you "zoom out" when you're describing a system? As in, electrons within an atom follow QM because you're talking about microscopic orbit, but electrons within the cathode ray tube follow CM because the "margin of error" is small enough to be negligible at visible scale?

Comment: @JJW Not necessarily - while it is often the case that "zooming in" reveals quantum effects, this is only a rule of thumb: There can in principle be macroscopic "quantum" phenomena (such as the fact the sun is burning, a thing only possible through the quantum nature of fusion, but the sun is very large).

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: i have to add there are large dimension  quantum mechanical effects , as in superconductivity https://quantum.lassp.cornell.edu/lecture/superconductivity

Comment: A slightly banal but very important instance of macroscopic quantum phenomena is the stability of matter! If atoms were classical, they would be unstable and the electrons would inspiral immediately, eliminating all chemistry and bonding and thus any of the features of matter that we experience.